# Disable desktop user-agents

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, desktop, user-agent

I've got a website currently running.
I would like for ONLY mobile users to be able to use the website.

So anyone who is on a desktop, it will show a 404 error or such.
How can I go about doing this?

Would user-agents be the proper way to go about doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes  detect the uger agents and redirect to an error page or welcome page from a filter on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using screen size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width => 699) {
document.location = "Yoursite/404";
}

</script>
```